# pandas DataFrame.rename unexpected keyword argument "axis" when using mapper

Tags: python, pandas

Following the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) I tried the following (verbatim out of the docs):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df.rename(str.lower, axis='columns')
```

yet I'm getting the error

> TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"

I also tried

```
df.rename(mapper=str.lower, axis='columns')
```

but then I get:

> TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "mapper"

Am I looking at an old version of the docs?

Comment: Probably you have an old version. See this old documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: @koalo I'm on '0.20.3' and can reproduce. EDIT: Huh I'm already out of date? This is what came with Anaconda this month.

Comment: It's the other way round. axis keyword was introduced in 0.21.1 and doesn't work with the earlier version. See this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#rename-reindex-now-also-accept-axis-keyword

Comment: They completely overhauled the rename API in the latest release. You seem to be running 0.21 code on an old version of pandas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Am I looking at an old version of the docs?

No, quite the opposite, in fact. You're looking at the latest version (`0.21` as of now). I'm pretty sure you have an older version of pandas.

In the older version, Some of the functions used `axis` to specify index/columns, whereas other functions used `index=...` or `columns=...`. To alleviate this, the devs have made an overhaul of many of the APIs to make them more consistent with each other. `rename` is one of them.

The code you have works just fine on the latest release, but not anything older, because `mapper` and `axis` were introduced in `0.21`.

For reference, on older versions, the following alternatives all work -

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

And,

```
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns.str.lower())))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try update in the morning. Is there a way I can view an older version of the docs online? So if I check what version I'm running, how could find the online docs for that version of `rename`? I guess I can view the docstring of the function I have locally.

Comment: @Dan in your terminal you can find out your version with pd.__version__. Once you’ve got this, go to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html and navigate to your version. Then on the side pane, search for the function docs you want to view.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using python2 with an old version of pandas.  The `axis` parameter isn't implemented yet for you.  You have 3 choices.  Either remove the `axis` parameter and explicitly name columns, as shown below, or pass a map to `rename(...)`, or else update your version of python and pandas.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import sys 
print(sys.version) 
print(pd.__version__)

#create a dataframe with two columns named Foo and BAR 
df = pd.DataFrame({" Foo": [1, 2, 3], "BAR ": [4, 5, 6]}) 
print(df)

#rename the columns in the dataframe to strip whitespace and be all lowercase: 
df = df.rename(columns={c:c.strip().lower() for c in df.columns}) 
print(df)

#change the column named foo to moo, and change the column named bar to baz 
df = df.rename(columns={"foo": "moo", "bar": "baz"}) 
print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
2.7.16 [GCC 4.9.3]
0.16.2
    Foo  BAR 
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

   foo  bar
0    1    4
1    2    5
2    3    6

   moo  baz
0    1    4
1    2    5
2    3    6
```